# Is it possible to implement 64-bit cmpxchg from 32-bit cmpxchg?

Tags: parallel-computing

#### Question

Given a 32-bit cmpxchg operation as a primitive:

```
u32 cmpxchg32(u32* mem, u32 key, u32 old, u32 neo) {
    // this function runs atomically
    u32 found = mem[key];
    if (found == old) {
        mem[key] = neo;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Is it possible to implement the same function, for 64-bits?

#### What I've tried

So far, the only progress I've had is [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a3c0/bcd9fa940181561473beb6b69e731bd3c1a1.pdf), which describes a method for implementing multi-word cmpxchg based on single-word primitives. It works for arbitrary lengths, though, and uses linked lists, insertion sort and additional heavy-weight structures to accomplish that. It, thus, looks overkill for my case, so I wonder if there is a more straightforward approach for the 32-bit -> 64-bit case.